# Embedding youtube or vimeo video in comment or messages like facebook

Tags: video, iframe, embed

I am looking for a tutorial or tips on how to embed a youtube or vimeo URL in a way that the URL turns in to the video and the text stays in place. Something like facebook's message or status update where you can drop a url of a video and it embeds itself. I know about iframe, but I don't want to use plugins.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is what you want, but you can use the old embed code instead of `iframe`.

Go to the video. Click Share. Select "Use old embed Code." You should get embed code that doesn't use `iframe`.

If this is not what you want, tell me, and I'll delete this post.

Comment: Thank  you for your response, but this is not what I am looking. I am looking for a way of coding to do this embedding thing automatically. I have created this comment box and I have written a php code that parses and grabs the id of the video and then finds the video and shows it on the screen. However, I am looking to see if somebody has done this in other ways.